# Why doesn't retrieving key values from locals() work in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, local-variables

**EDIT: Use `globals()` because `locals()` contains the list comprehension's namespace**

If I have a name, e.g. `navy_blue = 50`

And I run this code:

```
lst = []
for name in tuple(locals()):
    if "blue" in name:
        lst.append(locals()[name])

print(lst)
# [50]
```

It would have iterated over the locals() dict as a tuple and check whether or not each variable/name contains "blue" and whichever ones do, get appended. Right?

If I tried to do it like this:

`lst = [locals()[name] for name in tuple(locals()) if "blue" in name]`

I get the error of `KeyError: 'blue'`

But if I do something like,

```
xyz = locals()
lst = [xyz[name] for name in tuple(locals()) if "blue" in name]
```

It works. Obviously a clean list comprehension is ideal, but the code I thought would do the trick, isn't.
Why does the error come up?

Comment: I feel like whatever you're trying to do here could be done better some other way, such as a dictionary. Just because Python let's you do things like this doesn't mean you should

Answer (score 0):

`locals()` in a list comprehension only contains variables defined in that list comprehension. Replace `locals()` with `globals()` and it will work just as you want it to!